# Object manager taking too long to create/inject a dependency

Tags: magento2, magento-community

I am trying to inject a model via **Object Manager** in an integration test. The **injection/creation** of object takes forever and never ends. However, when I try print_r before calling **get/create** on object manager instance, I see the dump response on the console and test ends so the issue is clearly not with the tests not running but rather with Object manager creation.

```
class RemoveAbandonedCartDataOlderThanAMonthCronTest extends AbstractController {

/**
 * @var Abc\AbandonedCart\Cron\RemoveAbandonedCartDataOlderThanAMonthCron
 */
private $cron;

/**
 * @var Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection
 */
private $resourceConnection;

protected function setUp() {
    parent::setUp();

    $this->resourceConnection = $this->_objectManager->get('Abc\AbandonedCart\Model\AbandonedCart');
 }
}
```

[image]

**magento/product-community-edition: 2.3.5**

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

However, this might seems awkward but the issue was fixed with scope resolution operator.

`$this->_objectManager->get(\Abc\AbandonedCart\Model\AbandonedCart::class);`